# Fix Nginx triggering firewall alert DOUBLE DECODING ATTACK

Tags: rabbitmq, firewall, nginx-reverse-proxy

I currently have the following Nginx configuration on my RabbitMQ server:

```
 location ~* /rabbitmq/api/(.*?)/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:15672/api/$1/%2F/$2?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* /rabbitmq/(.*) {
        rewrite ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:15672;
        allow 185.96.158.10;
        deny all;
    }
```

The redirection seems to create mayhem with our firewall (pfSense) and we get plenty of alerts like this one:

```
Feb 7 10:20:35  snort   24797   [119:2:1] (http_inspect) DOUBLE DECODING ATTACK [Priority: 3] {TCP} 185.X.X.X:36127 -> 46.X.X.X:80
```

Could someone explain what the problem is and how could i rewrite the Nginx configuration in order to avoid triggering the alert?

Comment: Could it be the %2F ? [ie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Double_Encoding)

Comment: This part is required for the redirection... so can't really remove it unfortunately.